# Javascript or Jquery to validate a set of radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, radio-button

How do I get a condition validation for the following using javascript or jquery:

If I select "Yes", I am a vegetarian..I must select a veggie
If I select "No", I am NOT a vegetarian..I must select a Non veggie

```
<div>
<input name="Vegetarian" type="radio" value="1">Yes
<input name="Vegetarian" type="radio" value="0">No
</div>
..
<input name="Veggie" type="radio" value="veggieburger">Veggie Burger
<input name="Veggie" type="radio" value="fruit">Fruit
<input name="Veggie" type="radio" value="tofu">Tofu
<input name="Veggie" type="radio" value="salad">Salad
...
<input name="NonVeggie" type="radio" value="hamburger">Hamburger
<input name="NonVeggie" type="radio" value="chicken">Chicken
<input name="NonVeggie" type="radio" value="fish">Fish
<input name="NonVeggie" type="radio" value="turkey">Turkey
```

Comment: I love stack overflow :)

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var isVegetarian = $("input[name='Vegetarian']:checked").val() == "1";

    if (isVegetarian && $("input[name='Veggie']:checked").length == 0) {
        alert("Please select a vegetarian option");
    }
    else if (!isVegetarian && $("input[name='NonVeggie']:checked").length == 0) {
        alert("Please select a non-vegetarian option");
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jCKgy/)

If you have various forms throughout your site I'd recommend using [jQuery validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation). If this form is a one off, then this method is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you Rory for the example!

Answer (score 1):

Simply asking for a solution without having tried anything will not get you much of a response here. SO will not do your work for you.

I'll point you in the right direction.

You could use an onClick event to enable/disable one group of radio buttons when you click on the first group, forcing the user to select an entry from the correct group.

Check out the documentation on the jQuery site - it is actually very easy to get a hang of.

[.click() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
[Selectors - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to show/hide these options based on the Vegetarian option selection. Try this.

```
$('input[name=Vegetarian]').click(function(){
    $('input[name=Veggie]').parent().toggle(this.value == "1");
    $('input[name=NonVeggie]').parent().toggle(this.value != "1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate an according food, try this:

```
var name = $('input[name=Vegetarian]').val() == '1' ? 'Veggie':'NonVeggie';

return $('input[name='+ name +']').is(':checked');
```

Comment: Thank you sinsedrix for the example!

Comment: You asked about validation, not about hiding some inputs or bind some events and that's what I did. Thank me with a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [form validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation),

```
jQuery("#id_of_form").validate({
        rules: {
           "Veggie": {
                required : function(element){
                    return $("input[name='Vegetarian']:checked").val() == "1"
                }
            },
            "NonVeggie": {
                required : function(element){
                    return $("input[name='Vegetarian']:checked").val() == "0"
                }
            }
        }
});
```